# Passing the local variable as the argument for a function inside the parent function

Tags: javascript, closures

Here is the code that I ran and got the code of the inner function as the output. I don't understand why the local variable of the parent function can't be passed on as the argument for the child function.

```
function closure (value,num) {
    var num1 = num * value;
    return function (num1) {
        var r = value/num1;
        return r;
    };
}
console.log( closure(9,3) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

closure returns a function, which takes a parameter num1. Inside the scope of the function definition, num1 is the parameter, not the variable from the outer scope. The code should work if you just remove the parameter:

```
function closure(value,num) {
    return function() {
        return(value/(num*value));
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
new_function=closure(9,3); //No output: the inner function has not been executed yet
console.log(new_function()); //Output: the function is executed
```

or:

```
console.log(closure(9,3)());
```

Comment: Ok. The 'num1' that I sent as a parameter to the anonymous function is not the same 'num1' which is the local variable of the closure function. Also, I need to call the function with the (). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the local variable from the outer scope, you can just use it - you don't need to "pass it on".

In fact you are declaring a parameter for the inner function here, which is itself a variable local to the inner function that does - given it has the same name - shadow the outer variable. You seem to want either

```
function closure(value) {
    return function(num1) {
        return value/num1;
    };
}
console.log(closure(9)(3));
```

or

```
function closure(value,num) {
    var num1 = num*value;
    return function() {
        return value/num1;
    };
}
console.log(closure(9,3)());
```

Answer (score 1):

You made two mistakes.

1. You created a `num1` parameter when it already existed in the above scope. To clarify, you don't need to do `return function(num1)` because you already declared `num1` right above it.
2. You never called the closure function you returned. `closure(9,3)` returns a function, but you need to actually call it by doing `closure(9,3)()`

Here is the correct code for what you were trying to do:

```
function closure(value, num) {
  var num1 = num * value;
  return function() {
    var r = value / num1;
    return r;
  };
}

console.log(closure(9,3)());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear about what you're trying to achieve, but you must call the inner function with the local variable as argument in order to observe the results you're probably expecting.

```
function closure(value,num) {
    var num1 = num*value;
    return (function(number) {
    var r = value/number;
    return r;
})(num1);
}
console.log(closure(9,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `num1` as a parameter to the closure, which is not how this works. `num1` is within scope of the closure so it will access it without passing it via arguments in any way. That's how closures work.

You then add a set of parenthesis to your `closure()` call, like so: `closure(9,3)()` which will execute the closure/returned function in question. I've also simplified your code/function as it contained redundancies.

```
function closure (value, num) {
    return function () {
        return value / (num * value)
    }
}
console.log( closure(9,3)() );
```